# How to Add WooCommerce Product Categories in Custom Post Type

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

```
$args = array(
    'label'               => __( 'Eventr', 'dnp_theme' ),
    'description'         => __( 'What clients say ', 'dnp_theme' ),
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
    'taxonomies'          => array( 'Eventr', 'product_cat'),
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'public'              => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => false,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'menu_position'       => 10,
    'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-images-alt2',
    'can_export'          => true,
    'has_archive'         => false,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'capability_type'     => 'post',
);

register_post_type( 'Eventr', $args );
```

This is My Code Using to Get Woocommerce Product Categories in my Custom Post type.

In Taxonomies i have add woocommerce product category taxonomies "product_cat" but it not to show on admin panel.

Help me to know How to add WooCommerce Product Categories in Custom Post Type Admin Menu.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by this "In Taxonomies i have add woocommerce product category taxonomies "product_cat" but it not to show on admin panel." ? Also, you should wrap your code in a function and attach it to the `init` hook.

Comment: Our Wordpress Category Taxonomies is "category" or we can say it is slug. When add custom post type we can add category in taxonomies for category options but i want to add woocommerce product categories in my custom post type. thats slug is product_cat so i add it at the place of category but no category option show in admin of wordpress

Answer (score 7):

I was having the same issue, and I found that registering the taxonomy afterwards seemed to work. So in your functions after registering the custom post type, add something like this, where `custom_post_type` key is the key you registered:

```php
add_action( 'init', 'add_product_cat_to_custom_post_type' );
function add_product_cat_to_custom_post_type() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'product_cat', 'custom_post_type' );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To anyone having this issue in 2020 and with the Gutenberg editor:

**Step 1:**
Register the taxonomy either using `register_taxonomy_for_object_type` or by setting it in the post type registration arguments using the `taxonomies` field (as in the other answers and the question).

**Step 2:**
Include the taxonomy in the REST API and *make it available in the block editor* by setting `show_in_rest` to `true`.
For `product_cat`, this means to change this setting using the `woocommerce_taxonomy_args_product_cat` filter.

Answer (score 1):

Use the function `register_taxonomy_for_object_type()` called on `init`, but make sure the timing is right so that this call fires after your CPT registration. Notice the use of 99 as the priority setting in this case.

```
// attach product category taxonomy to "service" post type
add_action( 'init', function() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'product_cat', 'service' );
}, 10, 99);
```